# What does write_time and write_count actually mean in psutil.disk_io_counters?

Tags: io, profiling, monitoring, monitor, psutil

I'm trying to capture disk I/O metrics on my system. I found that psutil is exactly what I need. However, their [documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#disks) is a little vague in what write_time and write_count actually are. Is write_count the number of writes to the disk in the entirety of its lifetime? I am especially interested in write_time but am totally unsure as to how to utilize it. Thanks in advance